# How do I uninstall Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uninstall

I run Windows 7. Created a 90GB partition with 4GB swap memory to install Ubuntu 12.10 on. I've decided not to bother with Ubuntu, at least for now on this computer.

Do I simply just delete the 2 partitions (90GB + 4GB) by right clicking them in disk management "delete volume"?

**Separate question:**

I have files in Ubuntu, but can I just transfer them to Windows to keep them? I tried doing this in Ubuntu with 1 TV Show episode. I then restarted and booted Windows 7 and the file was in my files and was able to play it without a problem. So I just do this for all my files in Ubuntu I gather?

When I boot-up my laptop, Ubuntu loads automatically after the 10 second countdown.

This is just an "fyi" before you answer my original question.

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  http://askubuntu.com/q/137318/44179

Comment: Yes, you can just copy your files back to Windows, though I recommend backing them up to external media, like a flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

Boot up the computer from your Windows 7 USB memory stick or DVD. Then choose to run their repair tool. That will restore the boot manager. On your next boot you won't see the GRUB menu anymore, i.e. Windows will boot up directly. Then you are free to delete the two Ubuntu partitions, which can be done in Windows.

As always when you are fiddling around with partitions and such, don't forget to backup your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely move all your data to Windows file system and remove linux partitions.

**WARNING!** Before you deleted your linux partition note following.

If you have Windows installed on the same drive run `fixmbr` first! Then remove Linux partitions (including swap), as mentioned before.

Ubuntu Linux replaces MBR record with its own boot loader. If you just delete linux partitions you'll get unbootable drive. To fix it just boot from Windows 7 installation media, choose "Repair your computer", then "Command prompt" and run `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`.